# How to use cmake to get rapidcheck (property based testing) working in C++?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, property-based-testing

I'd like to do some property-based testing in a C++ library I'm working on, and was thinking of going with RapidCheck unless somebody has a better idea. (I will need, for example, to generate arbitrary `std::set<int>`, and if I can place bounds on the range of `int` in the sets and the size of the sets, all the better.)

All this being said, I'm still a bit of a cmake newb. There appear to be no instructions in RapidCheck except to include it as part of the source code (although downloading it would be better). I have gotten to the point where I can include the headers for RapidCheck in my code, but when I try to build any app using RapidCheck, I'm told that there are symbols from RapidCheck missing or that the rapidcheck library is missing.

I'm assuming that I have to build RapidCheck itself as part of the project to generate the library, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this and it seems difficult to find any examples where this is done.

Does anyone have any suggestions of examples where such things are done so that I can see the string of commands necessary to build a 3rd party API and include the library when building the executables, or - even better - an example of a project using RapidCheck that does exactly this? The lack of documentation on how to set this up is discouraging.

I hope this is not overly vague. To summarize, what I'd like to do from cmake:

1. Preferably download RapidTest (although including the files directly from the RapidTest project would be fine as well).
2. Run the required commands and set up the necessary variables to have my test code (in `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test`) be able to access RapidTest headers.
3. Generate (if necessary) the RapidTest library and make it so that I can link it to the tests I'm running.

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the right way to do this, but maybe it will help:

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

```sh
# from within the root of the rapidcheck repo:
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
# Leave off the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag if you don't need an SO.
$ make
```

That built: `librapidcheck.so` and `librapidcheck.a`, which you can then copy / install as needed.

You'll also need the `include` directory with the headers for rapidcheck, but that's just in the source tree.

Add the include path to your compile commands using whatever build tool you want, and link with the compiled libraries (the `.so` and `.a`)